# Is it possible to see your deleted questions or answers anywhere?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, deleted-questions

I was wondering if there is anyway to view your deleted questions or answers as sometimes I remove an answer or question but would like to see it at a later date

Comment: You can see recently deleted questions and answers in your profile - look at the bottom in the questions/ answers tabs where it says "recently deleted..."

Comment: hahaha, never spotted that!  but it would be good if it wasn't limited to the last 2 months

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Deleted posts are not discoverable by searches or links (except for the recently deleted link on your profile page) from *within* Stack Exchange.

If you know what questions you answered you can always see your deleted answers if you visit the question page.

If you have the url of your deleted question you will be able to see it.

Therefore the only sure-fire way of doing this is to bookmark all your questions and answers somewhere other than on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Yeah, but this means that they wouldn't be searchable through the so search bar and you'd have to pretty much remember each one to go to the one you wanted.  If they're keeping them like this, then why not just make them accessible via that deleted questions / answers link

Comment: @Pete - I'm not saying it's ideal. As I moderator I *do* see deleted posts on profiles - my own included - and it can be useful at times and I do miss it on other sites. But the number of times I've actually **needed** to look at my deleted questions can be counted on the fingers of one thumb,

Comment: There is that link to recently (<60d) deleted questions / answers at the end of their respective tabs on your own profile.

Comment: Should be able to use the API to query it

Comment: @ChrisF I remember I bookmarked my old answer (that was removed along with off-topic question), and I planned to copy-paste that text (of my answer) somewhere else.. but now I can't find it.. could you please post me the link of my answer about Spring vs. Spring MVC vs. Spring Boot? or something like that.. I can't find it.. I'm <10k. I would very much appreciate this favour and next time I'll make sure to store URLs.

Answer (score 3):

- As other users mentioned in comments, there are [deleted recent posts links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185491/295232) on the tabs Questions and Answers in your profile. They only work for recent deleted posts (60 days or younger).
- If you have 10,000 reputation, you have access to the [`deleted:1` search operator](/help/privileges/moderator-tools).
- You *might* be able to find them via your reputation history, *if* they have been voted on. That creates reputation events, and those are visible even if they're long ago and have been reverted by deletion of the post. It's a slightly convoluted workaround which I originally posted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333518/295232):

> Go to the [reputation tab on your profile](/users/current?tab=reputation), check the 'show removed posts' option and navigate to the time around which you posted the question. Instead of having to open all date records manually, you can execute a small jQuery snippet in your browser console:
>
> ```
> $("a.expander-arrow-small-hide").click()
> ```
>
> If the post was voted on, it will show at least twice in the reputation history (maybe on another date if the deletion was later):
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find your deleted questions by going to the "Top Bar" > "Inbox", scrolling to the bottom, "see all inbox items", and looking for notifications on your deleted posts.