# Show me my own deleted questions and answers on my profile page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

First off let me start by saying I know about a [highly popular request on the main meta.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) However that is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) and hasn't had any official response for a while now.

I have also seen related [support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252715/is-it-possible-to-see-your-deleted-questions-or-answers-anywhere) [requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327238/is-it-possible-to-search-my-deleted-questions) and even another [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272538/show-your-deleted-questions-in-your-activity-history-only-visible-to-you?noredirect=1&lq=1) from 2014 but that again is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

I would find it highly useful to see my own deleted questions mainly so I can learn from my mistakes in the past. But also as I have learnt more about the site be able to change them into something that would be acceptable here and maybe even reopen them.

The reason that got me researching and asking this is that I have not got the curious badge yet. I looked into the [formula](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294498/4631427) and from the questions on my profile believe I should have gotten it. Obviously I know I have some deleted questions but I now have no way of finding them, at least until I get to 10k rep, a long way off yet.

I can see an argument against this saying that older posts might not be useful to you, as quoted from @Shog9:

> Stuff that was posted months or years ago? Not so much. Some of us have hundreds of these posts; rubbing our faces in them long after we've moved on is a recipe for grief. Even the introduction of "recent" functionality has caused some amount of drama from the more... high-strung... members of these sites, as they find themselves unable to move on from their mistakes fast enough. I think we've struck a reasonable balance, but it isn't without compromise on both sides.

But if implemented into another tab on your profile out of the way of your non deleted questions and answers they will not be rubbed in your faces. Instead they will be out of the way and only shown to a user who consciously decides to go and look for them.

So my feature request is, would it be possible to show my own deleted questions and answers to myself on my profile page?

Comment: [status-declined] *was* the official response. Why would you expect any further activity?

Comment: @CodyGray The same reason other people post the same feature request again a few years later. Because I would like to see it implemented, believe it would be useful and to see if the official stance has changed since then.

Comment: Well, I don't understand the rationale. If you're interested in those questions, why did you delete them in the first place?

Comment: @CodyGray They are from when I first started using the site and so didn't understand it well. Doesn't mean the questions are terrible, just means they are bad for the site and so were deleted. They might still have value to me and if I can edit them into shape might also provide value to the site. Also note that I didn't delete them, at least all of them anyway so that part of your argument falls flat.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder the times this seems to come up, it seems to be a 1 time need - "can I see my deleted questions so i can try to fix them".  Absent a need to constantly monitor them, seems like some thing that could just as easily be accomplished by asking a moderator to get you the links and then you could bookmark them or add them to your favorites.  I know it is not an ideal solution, but it seems to be the best option considering not everyone wants (or needs) to see their deleted content based on Shog's comment.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, things evolve, even our position as community evolve on subjects. there's no harm in asking again 2 years later. Just in case position have changed. Specially for a request a large number of people seems supporting...

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think moderators are busy enough without bugging them with something as trivial as this

Comment: @TheLethalCoder it's a one off request.  You drop into chat and you ask.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That doesn't make my point or the feature request invalid. I would rather not bother a mod for something I should be able to do myself.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I think the point that Shog is trying to make in his answer you quoted is not everyone wants to see (or needs to see it).  The "deleted recent posts" is already hidden behind a link, so I don't see how moving it to another tab is going to change his argument.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Not everyone wants to see everything on their profile yet its there. I can't remember the last time, if ever, I looked at the responses tab but it's a feature. If one person didn't want a feature every time one was suggested you'd never have any new features.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder the point I was trying to make with my last comment but probably didn't do a good job of - you really haven't brought much new to the request.  All you really said is "I think we really need it" and proposed a work around to the objection raised in a previous "decline" answer that is essentially what is already done.  I'm not for this or against it.  It would be nice to be able to see your old content once in a while, but I don't really care if it isn't there

Comment: Haha, [status-officially-responded]. Sorry, buddy :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Worth trying I suppose