# Answer Ban, only one answer I can edit (other ones deleted) require mod to list deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, post-ban

I have read all of the following post.
[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

> **Background (skipable)**
>
> I've used this site since I've started programming. It is extremely
>   useful for finding 99% of my problems. Most of my questions can be
>   answered within a 2 second search. Unfortunately 1% of my problems
>   I have are due to a hard time wording the issue, usually because it
>   involves two or more things interfering with one another. This usually
>   leads me to not ask a question but occasionally I'll be stuck long
>   enough to ask anyway. Most of the time I can figure out my issue
>   by talking through it with other users.
>
> Even after using this site for a long time I still have a low
>   reputation due to the above. This means I cannot comment on others questions,  up vote, etc..

I recently tried to answer two questions. The first one I had a problem with for a while. Even though it was asked 3 years ago, the answer lead a few people incorrectly so I added what worked for me. The answer has received +0 which is expected being an outdated question but I figured it might help out anyone else having that same issue.

The second answer I gave was a stab at an incomplete question. Since I am not allowed to write in the comment section due to my low reputation, I asked something for clarity, and then continued to answer it assuming it to be true. Apparently it wasn't, I was given a negative score for the answer so I deleted it thinking it wasn't helpful.

Now I have an automatic answer ban, preventing me from answering ever again. The only answer I can edit is to a question that was asked 3 years ago which I felt could help people but doubt it will get anymore attention.

After looking into other people having this same issue, now my only options for reversing my ban is to track down a moderator, have them list out any other answers I might have deleted (I can't remember any but I'm sure there is as banning someone over 1 question would be outrageous), and answer them with more details, hoping that the years since they've been asked they will still have someone kind enough to go back and up-vote an edited answer.

I think it is definitely worth my time to fix my old answers, but why is it something a moderator has to bring up? Why do I have to get a moderator (which I can't figure out how to PM) to list all my deleted answers. Wouldn't it be best if once banned you would receive a list of all your crappy answers and have it say, "These answers are not rated high enough to allow you to answer anymore." I know I'm not the best programmer or the best writer, but I am new and trying to contribute back to the community that has helped me.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341025/show-me-my-own-deleted-questions-and-answers-on-my-profile-page -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted

Comment: Thanks Kevin, these are related. But once given a ban it is required to see deleted posts, otherwise you get into situations like mine where I'm stuck in stalemate until a mod shows me my removed posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all five of your deleted answers, some of which are unrecoverable as a result of the question they were on being deleted:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46349066/19679
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30577419/19679
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26306560/19679
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24703855/19679
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20100286/19679

That second-to-last one was complete gibberish, so I don't know what was going on there.

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd to the last comment was definitely my cat jumping on the keyboard or something and me instantly deleting it.