# Do "deleted" questions ever get deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

In my profile, under questions, at the bottom of the page, there's a link to my "deleted questions." I feel that these are weighing me down in my question ban, and really want to get rid of them. I looked at [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252715/is-it-possible-to-see-your-deleted-questions-or-answers-anywhere), but it's about retreving the posts, not permanently deleting them.

Comment: Only in extreme circumstances, which is exceedingly rare, and is not going to happen when you've just asked a few bad questions.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine Do these weigh me down in question bans, then?

Comment: Yes they do count towards the question ban and they should be fixed/improved to have better chances to get out.

Comment: @Tom Really? Since these are deleted, I feel they shouldn't count.

Comment: @BentheCoder Then anyone with a question ban could simply delete their questions and continue asking... which kind of defeats the point.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine Yeah, I suppose.

Comment: @BentheCoder You might want to look at [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: Let's clear up something: the mission of Stack Overflow is to be a library of useful Q&A for *future visitors*. The purpose for posting a question should be to *provide value to future visitors*. The reason to delete questions is to remove useless entries and maintain the knowledge base. All your talk about permanently deleting stuff just because it inconveniences *you*  seems to miss the entire *everybody else* aspect of the site. This is most likely what led to your question ban. Without adjusting how and why you use the site, chance is you'll run into another question ban.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I've learned my lesson about that, but now I ***actually do*** have some questions that I've done tons of research on and have found zero SO posts on it.  It feels like this isn't very constructive to ban users from posting questions just because they didn't post perfect ones at from the beginning.

Comment: @BentheCoder - You are welcome to ask those questions. You are under a rate limit. While I sympathize with your desire to ask more than a single question, quickly, your past questions have proven you need that rate limit to guarantee you ask higher quality questions. Instead of overreacting and deleting a question, improve the question, so it can have the potential to be upvoted.

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0, contributing to the [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/75300203) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/75077397) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/75025227) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/74971622) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/74946188) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/74564338)

Comment: Ok.  I'll try improve my questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Do "deleted" questions ever get deleted?

No. Nothing is deleted, ever <sup>1</sup>. What can happen is that a post gets redacted to remove content that shouldn't have been posted in the first place. That still leaves the post but now with an extra redaction record.

> I feel that these are weighing me down in my question ban, and really want to get rid of them.

Yes, that is by design. It would be way too easy to post crap, test the waters, delete and then rinse-repeat. That is not where reviewers and voters want to spend their time on.

Let me [quote Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812) almost verbatim here to get the deleted posts matter thing out of the way:

> Whether a post was deleted is mostly irrelevant to the question ban.
>
> What matters are poorly-received posts. That is, questions that are downvoted, closed, or flagged as inappropriate in some way.
>
> The one exception involves deleting a question right after someone posts an answer to it.
>
> Where folks usually trip up is in thinking that if they delete all their crappy questions the system won't notice that they're bad at asking. [T]he only difference deletion makes is that **you can't fix a deleted question**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

---

1. barring mishaps, accidents, legal matters.

Comment: Re *"Nothing is deleted, ever"*: That is probably true in the wider sense, but there is the famous hard deletion by Atwood from the Stack Exchange database of the [podcast-featured boat programming question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408947/#comment852926_408947). (Part of Stack Overflow history;  referenced at 1 h 02 min 43 secs in [episode 50 of the Stack Overflow podcast](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-28), classic series (2009-04-21). [It was rescued](https://web.archive.org/web/20100426125115/http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/).)

Comment: (Though the entire SoundCloud archive seems to be broken now. Here [are](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-28) [other](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-77) [ones](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-73) which used to work. For the latter, the *[6 - 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)* part is (was) at 03 min 18 secs - 05 min 05 secs)